# c# configure socks5 to winforms

Tags: c#

I would like download source code from a socks5 connexion but the remote server doesn't change my IP Address, why ?

```
private string getSourceCode(string url)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        wc.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("******", "******");
        WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("195.201.**.**:****", false, null, wc.Proxy.Credentials);
        wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0");

        string sourceCode = wc.DownloadString(url);
        return sourceCode;
    }
MessageBox.Show(getSourceCode("http://ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You never assign the newly created `WebProxy` object to the `WebClient`.

Try it like this:

```
private string getSourceCode(string url)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("195.201.**.**:****", false, null, new NetworkCredential("******", "******"));
    wc.Proxy = myproxy; // THIS ONE WAS MISSING

    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0");

    string sourceCode = wc.DownloadString(url);
    return sourceCode;
}
```

MessageBox.Show(getSourceCode("http://ipv4bot.whatismyipaddress.com"));

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesn't work, the remote server returned me " An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException " in line of " DownloadString() "

Comment: Well if you could add details about your exception (message, exact stack trace, etc) I might be able to help. By the way you should consider closing this question and opening a new one as it may be a completely different problem